# Unity C# - Cannot perform upm operation: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined [NotFound]

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am developing a game 3D under UNITY ( Unity 2020.1.3f1 ) with C# on windows, all things everything was working fine, suddenly the following error appears :

***Cannot perform upm operation: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined [NotFound].See console for more details
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()***

[image]

And on the Package Manager in the Unity Registry i can't refreshing packages :

[image]

And the game on android crash on startup but it works on editor without any error

I found no explanation for this error and all the topics that talk about this error he talks about reactjs while I code with C# no relation with reactjs

Please Help me

Comment: Check your scene in Unity Editor. There could be a prefab with a missing component.

Comment: Thank you apollosoftware.org i checked all scenes all prefab are ok with their component

Comment: there's something else to check for this error  please ?

Comment: This problem lies in rows.map, so it can be speculated that the object calling map is undefined, not the map itself. You can see that there is a problem with this.state.selectedRows.

Comment: Thank you Housheng-MSFT 
The problem i don't have any object with the name map in my game, by the way i solved the problem with another way but until now this error doesn't have any explanation

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem after 3 weeks

I created a new 3D project with unity, and i copied all my assets on old project and past them on the new project after that some little bugs appears as scripts on object, function on buttons etc ...

and after the game works again without problem

until now i don't understand the error appeared and i don't find any explanation to that on unity support or on all forum of unity issue

For those who find this error make this solution that's work

Answer (score 0):

Update:
based on [this link](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1844685/cannot-perform-upm-operation-cannot-read-property.html) try removing and re-adding the "Test Framework" package from the package manager and re-open the project, it may fix the problem.(if it didn't help check the answer below)

I had this problem for any **imported** project on Unity 2019.4.10f1 and the best solution I found was upgrading the project to another version.
I used Unity **2020.20.7f1** and now the package manager is working properly on the same project
This may be a bug in some of unity 2019 subversions.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem like this

1. Close all Unity Editors
2. Log-out of Unity Hub and log-in again
3. Open the project again and check if Unity login is normal in the upper left corner
4. That's it